# Differentiation of a Probability Density

Tags: tensor-calculus, kinetic-theory

I am currently studying kinetic theory (particularly the Focker-Planck equation) in curvilinear coordinates.

The problem that arises when working in curvilinear coordinates is that the density $f$ itself is not coordinate invariant but

$f\; \mathsf{d}\vec{v}=f'\; \mathsf{d}\vec{v}'=f \sqrt(g) \; \mathsf{d}\vec{v}$,

where $g$ denotes the metric determinant, is indeed coordinate invariant, and denotes e.g. the probability of finding a velocity within the infinitesimal volume element $\mathsf{d}\vec{v}$ at a position.
The transformation rule described above, however, is the transformation property of a scalar density of weight one/ a top-form.
The question now is whether or not we can treat $f$ as a scalar density/ top form as

$f^{\otimes \Lambda}=f \mathsf{d}x^1 \wedge ... \wedge \mathsf{d}x^N$

where the notation $f^{\otimes \Lambda}$ is introduced to keep track of the basis.
And if so, how do we consider the basis vectors when differentiating or integrating the density function? Or do we need to consider them at all?
Differentiation should lead to additional Christoffel-terms in the usual manner.
(see e.g. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2267059/covariant-derivative-of-tensor-densities)

Furthermore, I would like to know where the basis comes from/ if it is just swept under the rug when working in a cartesian basis?

Any insight would be appreciated. Unfortunately, I have just started studying measure theory so I am not that knowledgeable in that regard.
Most information I have is from this Book concerning the Focker-Planck equation (https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-642-61544-3)